# Using SDWebImage to copy an image as NSData to Pasteboard

Tags: swift, nsdata, sdwebimage

I'm using `SDWebImag`e to load images into a `UICollectionView`. Then when the user clicks on the image I want to copy it to the `Pasteboard` so they can paste it into other apps.

The code I am currently using in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method goes back to the web to copy the image. But the image should already be in the user's cache.

How do I use `SDWebImage` to grab an image for `NSData`?

That way the app will first check the cache for the image. I keep running into `DataType` issues when I try to use `SDWebImage`.

This is my current code. I want to fix the code in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let iCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ImageCollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCollectionViewCell
    let url = NSURL(string: self.imgArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String)

    iCell.imgView.sd_setImageWithURL(url)

    return iCell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    // Change code below to use SDWebImage

    let url = NSURL(string: self.imgArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String)

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

    if data != nil {
        UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().setData(data!, forPasteboardType: kUTTypePNG as String)
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `let image = SDImageCache.sharedImageCache.imageFromDiskCacheForKey(url!); let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);`? You may need to check if `image` exist (image already in cache).

Comment: THANKS! This worked. And you are correct, I have to check if the image exists, otherwise it will crash if it's not there. I added an if statement to check that `image != nil` before `let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` else look for the image online with my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) has a cache. You can access it with `SDImageCache`. There is customization allowed (different namespaces for caches).

```
let image = SDImageCache.sharedImageCache.imageFromDiskCacheForKey(url!)‌
if image != nil
{
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
}
```

You have to check if `image` is not `nil` because the downloads are asynchrone. So user may trigger `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` whereas the image hasn't been downloaded yet, and per se not present in the cache.